# Add authentication keys to dropbear ssh?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, dropbear

For ssh I usually add keys to `/etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys` so that I can log in without entering a password. I recently discovered a few systems that use dropbear ssh instead of ssh/openssh. Is there an equivalent to authorized_keys for dropbear? Is there any way to add authorized keys for dropbear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears Dropbear is compatible with `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` public key authentication per [this documentation](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html). (And all documentation/setups I've seen from a quick Google search)

Answer (score 13):

Pretty old question, but in case someone has same problem.

You just need to put `authorized_keys` file into `/etc/dropbear` folder (in my case on Ugoos AM3 with Entware it was `/opt/etc/dropbear`).

Don't forget to do `chmod 0600 /etc/dropbear/authorized_keys`.

Ref: https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dropbear.public-key.auth

Comment: thanks, solved my problem.

`ln  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  /etc/dropbear/`

Comment: @yurenchen Beware the two files will become unlinked if one is edited with sed/perl/etc, or if a file is moved and replaced. Due to this, I sometimes use notes instead, such as `~/.ssh/authorized_keys_LOCATION` containing the correct path. Or at least use a symlink, which is easier to recognize than a hard link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers from @DimGun and @colealtdelete

I faced this 'opportunity' recently with my now dated Samsung tablet.  Unfortunately my tried and true ssh Android  app doesn't support older hardware/releases.

I found the [**`simpleSSHD`**](http://galexander.org/software/simplesshd/) app, this is a very serviceable  replacement  set-up so that you can only use `authorized_keys` for login.  `simpleSSHD` is based on the `DropBear` project.

That creates a bit of a *bootstrap* problem.  User notes seemed to assume a few things:

- [simpleSSHD Quick Start](http://galexander.org/software/simplesshd/)

An *easy way* approach (from my Linux) PC was to paste the new entry into my tablet's `authorized_keys` file in the `simpleSSHD` home directory.  You can do this by logging-in the first time with a one-time password.

On the PC ...

```
 #  add the tablet to the PC ~/.ssh/config file
 cat id_rsa.pub | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Puts the public key entry into my clipboard.  Or you can just select and copy.

Then `ssh` into the tablet:

```
 $ ssh linuxpc@192.168.xx.zz -p2222  
 The authenticity of host '[192.168.xx.zz]:2222 ([192.168.xx.zz]:2222)' can't be established.
 ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:oqsN8RKo9T990vjWiQEGooRBDUyId7yJG28eqGTAsa4.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
 Warning: Permanently added '[192.168.xx.zz]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
 linuxpc@192.168.xx.zz's password: 
 user@android:/data/data/org.galexander.sshd/files $ ls -l
 -rw------- u0_a142  u0_a142      1499 2019-03-13 09:05 dropbear.err
 -rw------- u0_a142  u0_a142         5 2019-03-13 08:52 dropbear.pid
 -rw------- u0_a142  u0_a142       243 2018-09-21 12:41 dropbear_ecdsa_host_key
 $ cat > authorized_keys                                                               
 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX= linuxpc@hostname
 [Ctrl/D]
 $ chmod 0600 authorized_keys
```

Now the tablet `simpleSSHD` service is ready for secure login.  Trial that with `filezilla` and ssh with no password, etc.

That all worked very nicely.  In addition, these days I can use the file browser without needing an FTP client with the path:

```
 sftp://linuxpc@192.168.xx.zz:2222//storage/extSdCard/Movies
```

Somewhat 1,000 times faster that *ye olde* MTP links.  It is advised to set the permissions on the parent directory to:  `0700` for the parent equivalent to: `~/.ssh` path.

Comment: Useful info.  However the sentence *"I found on simpleSSHD as a very serviceable DropBear based replacement"* is not normal English and requires too much interpolation to get the meaning.  "Instead of DropBear I used simpleSSHD and found it to be a good replacement".  Especially because the answer is not a direct answer to the question, you should make it immediately clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this on MacOS to connect to android devices using SSH-2.0-dropbear_2019.78

```
scp -P 2222 /Users/<USER_NAME>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@<IP_ADDRESS_FROM_DROPBEAR_APP>:/data/data/org.galexander.sshd/files/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just:

1. copy the text content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from the client machine.
2. log into dropbear server,
3. Redirect the contents of clipboard into an `authorized_keys` file using the `echo` command and paste the contents after echo (in quotes).

It would look like this: `echo "<paste from clipboard here>" >> authorized_keys`